# Android App build with Adobe Flash Builder requires STICKY BROADCAST permission. Why?

Tags: android, permissions, flash-builder, broadcast

Yesterday I wanted to deploy/publish my first Android app at google play store but get stuck on the STICKY_BROADCAST permission that is needed/added.

Explanation on the google play store permission tab of the app:

```
SEND STICKY BROADCAST 
Allows the app to send sticky broadcasts, which remain after the broadcast ends. Malicious apps may make the tablet slow or unstable by causing it to use too much memory. Allows the app to send sticky broadcasts, which remain after the broadcast ends. Malicious apps may make the phone slow or unstable by causing it to use too much memory.
```

I don't want that users may think that my app is an evil or slow app (BECAUSE I DON'T USE ANY STICKY_BROADCAST functionality in my CODE). How can i remove this permission or is it required by Adobe Air? Just one article found on the adobe site (with sort of same question) but without an answer.

In the app.xml configuration I defined only two permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>
```

I use the internet connection to get some configuration for the app. I use the vibrate ane of adobe examples to vibrate the phone when the user tap the screen.

Why is the permission SEND STICKY BROADCAST needed/added to the package when I deploy/publish the app and what can I do to avoid it. Or better: Is there a way to avoid this permission?

Comment: Anyone? The problem is still there after such a long time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have the same problem and I just discovered it was caused by the adobe air I packaged together with my apk file.
Either you tell the user to download adobe air or get a newer version of flex.

Sorry I am late, I started working with flash just last week.

Comment: Thanks to the answer. Don't use Flash Builder anymore. There is also another problem with the compiled apk's, Adobe/Flex uses an untrusted connection to some resource (can't remember what it was exactly), Google Play don't like it. Some old programs won't run on android 5 for example.  Also I think learning a wrapper language is not a good idea if you want to use hardware/OS features, you'll better learn the language of the platform. Also the excutable is native and not emulating stuff. If you want to create cross-platform apps, try webapps, it's cheaper, it's easier. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Alright thanks. It's just that my client specifically stated that they don't want HTML5

Comment: And also, I don't need hardware/OS features but most importantly, I can't afford an xcode for IOS on windows or even get an apple computer.....they re not paying much